# java low value ouput 0

Tags: java

I am a complete Newb with Java and I am having a very curious problem happening in my code. The object is to create a list of 20 random numbers in an array, to have this array displayed and to perform a series of calculations based on the data in the array. This has to be accomplished in 6 methods. Everything seems to work fine except for the last method. It is meant to grab the lowest number in the array but for some reason it is only outputting a 0. What's strange is that is works perfectly fine for the method above, which gathers the highest number in the array.

I tried to trouble shoot it and see if it were may from an array with null values, but this doesn't likely as the highest method seems to work fine. The lowestList is near the bottom.

Thank you for help, it is much appreciated to this greenhorn. Also if you have any other comments that would be terrific, I am open to criticism!

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Program7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int listSize = 20;    // List size
        double total = 0;           // Total
        int[] ranList = new int[listSize];  // Array with random numbers
        int highest = ranList[0];   // Highest variable
        int lowest = ranList[0];    // Lowest Variable

        randomNumberList(ranList);          // Calls randomNumberList method
        displayList(ranList);               // Calls displayList method
        total = totalList(total, ranList);  // Calls totalList method
        double averageList = listAverage(total, ranList);   // Calls averageList method
        highest = listHighest(ranList, highest);    // Calls listHighest method
        lowest = lowestList(ranList, lowest);   // Calls lowestList method

        // On screen output
        System.out.println("\nHere's the total: " + total);
        System.out.println("Here's the average: " + averageList);
        System.out.println("Here's the highest number in the list: " + highest);
        System.out.println("Here's the lowest number in the list: " + lowest);

    }

    /**
     * Generates a random list
     *
     * @param ranList
     */
    public static void randomNumberList(int[] ranList) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ranList.length; i++) {
            Random generator = new Random();
            int ranNum = generator.nextInt(100) + 1;
            ranList[i] = ranNum;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays list
     *
     * @param ranList
     */
    public static void displayList(int[] ranList) {
        System.out.println("Here is your random list: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < ranList.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(ranList[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds elements in list
     *
     * @param total
     * @param ranList
     * @return returns total of list added together
     */
    public static double totalList(double total, int[] ranList) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ranList.length; i++) {
            total += ranList[i];
        }
        return total;
    }

    /**
     * Finds average by dividing the total with the ranList.length
     *
     * @param total
     * @param ranList
     * @return result of the averaging
     */
    public static double listAverage(double total, int[] ranList) {
        double averageList = total / ranList.length;
        return averageList;
    }

    /**
     * Steps through array via loop and finds highest value
     *
     * @param ranList
     * @param highest
     * @return the highest value
     */
    public static int listHighest(int[] ranList, int highest) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ranList.length; i++) {
            if (ranList[i] > highest) {
                highest = ranList[i];
            }
        }
        return highest;
    }

    /**
     * Steps through array via loop and finds lowest value
     *
     * @param ranList
     * @param lowest
     * @return the lowest value
     */
    public static int lowestList(int[] ranList, int lowest) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ranList.length; i++) {
            if (ranList[i] < lowest) {
                lowest = ranList[i];
            }
        }
        return lowest;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting lowest to 0 before you ever pass it into the method.

```
int[] ranList = new int[listSize];  // Array with random numbers (not yet, right now this is an array of all 0)
int highest = ranList[0];   // Highest variable (not really, this is 0)
int lowest = ranList[0];    // Since you didn't put anything in ranList, lowest is now 0
```

For your highest function, this works fine because your random numbers are always higher than 0.

Really, the root cause here is that you shouldn't be passing anything into those methods at all, because they aren't doing anything.

```
public static int lowestList(int[] ranList) {
    int lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < ranList.length; i++){
        if (ranList[i] < lowest){
            lowest = ranList[i];
        }
    }
    return lowest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize highest and lowest after you create the random arrays. They're both starting out as 0.

Answer (score 0):

try to put

```
lowest = ranList[0];
```

after you generate your list i.e after you call

```
randomNumberList(ranList);
```